# installing DUnitX under C++ builder

Tags: c++builder, dunitx, c++builder-tokyo

How to install DUnitX under C++ builder?

I am working with Version 10.2.3. and I can't find any hints to use this testing framework in my projects.

Comment: C++Builder has it's own tags. C++ and Builder as separate tags are totally different things. I've corrected them for you, but you should remember that for the future. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the specific C++Builder version addressed in the question, 10.2.x:

Installation: The C++Builder installer for 10.2 lets you select components to install during the installation. DunitX is one of the selectable components.

Usage: Embarcadero documents how to use DunitX with C++Builder 10.2 [here in the overview page](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/DUnitX_Overview#Developing_C.2B.2B_DUnitX_Tests) ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211026222848/https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/DUnitX_Overview#Developing_C.2B.2B_DUnitX_Tests)).

However, in 2022, the current C++Builder Release 11 (11.1, 11.2) **no longer supports using DunitX** with C++, so you might want to consider using another unit testing framework. See Embarcadero's note on the same documentation [page for the current release](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/DUnitX_Overview) ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220923103006/https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/DUnitX_Overview)):

> Note: DUnitX uses Delphi language features that are not supported in C++. For C++ developers, DUnit is the best tool. C++ can also be tested using other frameworks such as Google Test, available via GetIt Package Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I made a mistake when I installed my update.